# YouTube API does not work in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

I am making a website where a video has to be shown, this video to hide the recommended videos and prevent the URL from being obtained, I established a layer in front of the video, then I put a div in front of the iframe so that it would not let interact with the video interface.
The problem I have is that when testing with FIREFOX it works correctly, when testing with Google Chrome, it does not work for me, the screen remains plastered, That is, when displaying the page, the embedded video has a layer as an image and a button, I do this with PlayerState.UNSTARTED, and adding the corresponding class to show me said image, playerWrap.classList.add ("ended") ;.
I have no error in the console.

However, if I try the same with Google Chrome, when displaying the page, the embedded video only keeps the image layer, it does not let me click to play video.
any idea why this happens?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="imgs/icon/favicon.ico">
    <style>
    .hytPlayerWrap{
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative
    }
    .hytPlayerWrap.unstarted::after{
    content:"";position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:64px 64px;
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTI4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNTEwIDUxMCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI1NSAxMDJWMEwxMjcuNSAxMjcuNSAyNTUgMjU1VjE1M2M4NC4xNSAwIDE1MyA2OC44NSAxNTMgMTUzcy02OC44NSAxNTMtMTUzIDE1My0xNTMtNjguODUtMTUzLTE1M0g1MWMwIDExMi4yIDkxLjggMjA0IDIwNCAyMDRzMjA0LTkxLjggMjA0LTIwNC05MS44LTIwNC0yMDQtMjA0eiIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==)
    }
    .hytPlayerWrap.ended::after{
    content:"";position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:64px 64px;
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMjgiIGhlaWdodD0iMTI4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNTEwIDUxMCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTI1NSAxMDJWMEwxMjcuNSAxMjcuNSAyNTUgMjU1VjE1M2M4NC4xNSAwIDE1MyA2OC44NSAxNTMgMTUzcy02OC44NSAxNTMtMTUzIDE1My0xNTMtNjguODUtMTUzLTE1M0g1MWMwIDExMi4yIDkxLjggMjA0IDIwNCAyMDRzMjA0LTkxLjggMjA0LTIwNC05MS44LTIwNC0yMDQtMjA0eiIgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==)
    }

    .hytPlayerWrap.paused::after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:0;
    bottom:50px;
    right:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:40px 40px;
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEiIHdpZHRoPSIxNzA2LjY2NyIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNzA2LjY2NyIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEyODAgMTI4MCI+PHBhdGggZD0iTTE1Ny42MzUgMi45ODRMMTI2MC45NzkgNjQwIDE1Ny42MzUgMTI3Ny4wMTZ6IiBmaWxsPSIjZmZmIi8+PC9zdmc+)}
    .hytPlayerWrap.ended iframe,
    .hytPlayerWrap.paused iframe{
    visibility: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
    .hytPlayerWrap {
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .yt-cover{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      left:0;
      z-index:1000;
}

    </style>

    <title>Congreso Intessrnacional 2021</title>
</head>
<body id="plenario">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-12">
        <br><br><br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                
                <div class="hytPlayerWrapOuter" >
                    <div class="hytPlayerWrap" style="background-image:url(imgs/intro22.png)">
                        <iframe id="yt-frame" width="605" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6XYzWjixpwE?rel=0&autoplay=1&mute=0&control=1&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=0&fs=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&nologo=1" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
                        <div class="yt-cover"></div>
</div>

                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="col-2">&nbsp;</div> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="seccion-regresar-plenario"> 
        <a class="boton-regresar-plenario" href="salones.php"></a>
    </div>  

</div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/utiles.js"></script>    

<script>
    "use strict";
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        if (window.hideYTActivated) return;
        let onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks = [];
        for (let playerWrap of document.querySelectorAll(".hytPlayerWrap")) {
            let playerFrame = playerWrap.querySelector("iframe");
            let tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            let firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            let onPlayerStateChange = function (event) {

                 if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.UNSTARTED) {
                    playerWrap.classList.add("ended");
                }
                else if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                    playerWrap.classList.add("ended");

                } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                    playerWrap.classList.add("paused");
                } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                    playerWrap.classList.remove("ended");
                    playerWrap.classList.remove("paused");
                }
            };
            let player;
            onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks.push(function () {
                

                player = new YT.Player(playerFrame, {events: {'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange}});
            });
            playerWrap.addEventListener("click", function () {
                let playerState = player.getPlayerState();
                if (playerState == YT.PlayerState.UNSTARTED) {
                        player.playVideo();
                }
                else if(playerState == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                    player.seekTo(0);
                } else if (playerState == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
                        player.playVideo();
                   }
            });
        }
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
            for (let callback of onYouTubeIframeAPIReadyCallbacks) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        window.hideYTActivated = true;
      
    });


</script>  



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *it does not work* doesn't mean much ... *the screen remains plastered* means even less... first step - check the browser developer tools console for errors - (anyone else find the irony delicious that youtube API works in firefox but not in chrome?)

Comment: you are right, update my question,.

Comment: I'd scatter some console.log's into your code to see what is happening